# How to send boolean as parameter using the library Android Asynchronous Http Client?

Tags: android, android-async-http, http-request-parameters

I'm using the [aync http lib](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) to make my requests, and I need to post some data to a service, that includes a boolean parameter.

But the boolean parameter is not putted in my params.

Is it not possible to put a boolean in the RequestParams like this?

```
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("comment", comment);
    params.put("extra", false);
```

Comment: I also would like to know this.I have used only strings so far.You can send a "0" or "1" instead just to make things work temporarily but yes it's interesting to know about `boolean` being passed.

Comment: Yes. I am doing this same workaround, send "0" or "1". 
I found a link in the documentation where are showed examples with many data types, but anyone using boolean. 
Link: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.html